# Problem with migrating from Texture2D to CCTexture2D (Setting CCSprite texture)

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

My problem is that whenever I change the texture of a sprite, the new texture will retain the size of the original sprite's texture.

I have this code:

```
mySprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"mySprite.png"]];

...

// change current stage here 

CCTexture2D *newTexture=[[[CCTexture2D alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"stage number %d.png",currentStageNumber]]]autorelease];

[mySprite setTexture:newTexture];
```

The new sprite is stretched or compressed depending on the size of the original sprite.
If the original sprite is larger, the new texture is stretched.

I didn't have this problem when I was using cocos2d v0.8

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8):

Solved:

```
mySprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"mySprite.png"]];

...

// change current stage here

CCTexture2D *newTexture=[[[CCTexture2D alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"stage number %d.png",currentStageNumber]]]autorelease];

[mySprite setTexture:newTexture];

[mySprite setTextureRect:CGRectMake(0,0, newTexture.contentSize.width, newTexture.contentSize.height)];
```

:)

Comment: The `setTextureRect` call is the magic thing that makes this work.  Without it your new texture may be horribly distorted if your sprite has a custom scale-factor applied to it.

Answer (score 0):

or:

```
  CCTexture2D* texture=[[CCTexture2D alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sky" ofType:@"png"]]  ];
    CCSprite *sprTile=[CCSprite spriteWithTexture:texture];

    [self addChild:sprTile];
    [texture release];
```